# Cannot find the Black Lower Left Triangle in LaTeX

Tags: symbols

I needed to use the symbol "Black Lower Left Triangle" from "Segoe UI Symbol" in Latex but I cannot find how to write it?
Any help? Thanks i advance!

Comment: you want `\blacktriangleleft` from `mathabx` or fourier `package`?

Comment: @touhami, I am searching for this one: [http://graphemica.com/%E2%97%A3](http://graphemica.com/%E2%97%A3)

Comment: Ok, try `\llblacktriangle` from `stix` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[latex symbols list](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix}
\begin{document}
$\llblacktriangle$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wish I could install the `stix` package because till now I cannot :(

Comment: yes you need to install it.

Comment: Yes, I see that I have to install it but for some reasons I cannot install neither through the internet nor manually !!! Thanks a lot, really.